# How power affects heating of a coil

Tags: electric-circuits, power

So I am doing a little research on my own about electronic cigarettes. Most Ecig users value high power at a standard current. This means they buy very expensive, high voltage batteries and put high resistance resistors on them to maintain the optimal current.

The only reason I can see people doing this is if power allowed them to use longer coils and get more surface area to burn product on. Thus allowing them to get a "bigger hit".

So does power directly relate to length in my situation? Some equations would be really helpful as well. Everything that I google just goes into how to reduce heat by lowering current.

Comment: not very clear.